# Dilemma: avoiding the assumption of gender without narrowing one's vocabulary

Tags: discusión, petición-de-funcionalidad

Diego asked an [interesting question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23963/9385) about how to remain gender-ambiguous when  writing in Spanish, and guifa wrote a helpful [answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23964/9385).  A [related question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15554/9385), posed in 2015, received several interesting answers.  Although I learned some new tricks from these answers, let's face it, Spanish isn't the easiest language to retain gender ambiguity in.  Trying to keep things neutral in an online setting such as SE can be awkward and unwieldy in Spanish.

Hence a proposal.  Could we agree not to assume a participant's gender, even if the participant uses an adjective that appears to refer to a male person, e.g. "cansado"?  Notes:

- Some people prefer not to identify as male or female in their day-to-day life
- Some people have a similar preference with regard to their public persona on the internet, even though they might identify as male or female in face-to-face interactions
- Motivation for one or both of these policies can vary from person to person

Proposed exception to the above proposal: if the username obviously indicates one gender or the other, or if the participant has clearly indicated personal gender (for example, if the participant writes, "When I gave birth a year ago" in a post, or "I'm so-and-so's brother").

Here's the proposal again, restated.  Suppose someone participates here with a user name that leaves one guessing, such as Botón, and chooses to leave their gender unknown in their writing on the site.  I'm proposing that we allow ourselves to use male pronouns and adjectives when speaking to Botón, or about Botón.  And I'm proposing that these pronouns and adjectives NOT be taken to mean that Botón is necessarily male.  Maybe Botón identifies as male in the grocery store; maybe Botón identifies as female; we don't know and won't know unless Botón chooses to disclose this information.

Es decir, si Botón escribe

> Cuando llegué a la casa el viernes, estaba cansadísimo

**propongo que nadie lo tome como una declaración de ser hombre.**  Y vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que eso debe ser decisión personal de cada usuario.

Yo no tengo problema en escribir en español de una manera neutral en cuanto a género*. Reconozco que es más fácil en inglés, por supuesto, pero en español también se puede hacer, aunque a veces se fuercen un poco las palabras.

Pero es que esto, en el fondo, es más una ventaja que un inconveniente: en español resulta facilísimo dejar claro desde el principio el género con el que te identificas. Vienes de una cultura anglosajona, y ahí sí es un problema, precisamente porque el lenguaje dificulta el especificar un género. Pero no aquí (creo). ¿Te identificas como mujer? Escribe en femenino. ¿Te identificas como hombre? Escribe en masculino. ¿No quieres revelar tu género? Escribe usando construcciones neutras, o en inglés.

Por eso mismo, si alguien se refiere a su persona usando adjetivos en un género concreto al escribir en español, no veo por qué motivo no hemos de asumir que ese es el género con el que se identifican. Si a esa persona le molesta que se asuma un género que no corresponde, entonces debería tener más cuidado al escribir y no dar a entender un género que no es, o bien directamente especificar cuál prefiere.

Me parece mucho más peligroso este otro criterio:

> *if the username obviously indicates one gender*

¿Obviamente para quién? ¿Una mujer no puede usar el alias Francisco de Quevedo sin que por ello asuman que es un hombre? ¿Un hombre no puede usar el alias Rosa Parks sin que por ello asuman que es una mujer?

¿Qué será lo siguiente: basarnos en si usan falda o pantalón? (/sarcasm).

La línea es muy fina y es un tema en el que no se puede contentar a toda la comunidad.
Creo que lo mejor es que el stack intervenga lo menos posible (siempre que las conversaciones no entren en el terreno del abuso, claro) y se deje al sentido común de cada cual la decisión de cómo hablar.

<sub>* Ejemplo: esta misma respuesta.</sub>

<sub>PD: Aunque me parezca un buen tema de debate, voto negativo porque no estoy de acuerdo con la propuesta y parece que el criterio es votar sí / no, aunque la pregunta no esté marcada como propuesta.</sub>

Comment: ¿Cómo se marca como propuesta? // *"Si a esa persona le molesta que se asuma un género que no corresponde, entonces debería tener más cuidado al escribir y no dar a entender un género que no es, o bien directamente especificar cuál prefiere."* ¿Y si el género es ambiguo, es decir, no está definido?  Walen, la pregunta de Diego no ha recibido mucha atención.  Hay una respuesta y es bastante buena, pero hay muchas frases comunes de manejo de SE que no se han resuelto todavía.  Te invito a aportar tus ideas en https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23963/9385.